# How to proof: if $A\subset B \rightarrow f^{-1}(A)\subset f^{-1}(B)$ and show that it can't work conversely?

Tags: functions, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Hello so I was wondering how you can prove $A\subset B \rightarrow f^{-1}(A)\subset f^{-1}(B)$. I found someone with a similar problem on stack exchange but didn't  found it much of a proof.

I know if you have $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a function with e.g. $K\subset Y$ then the inverse image is $f^{-1}(K)=\{x\in X \mid f(x)=K \}$. Which also means that $x\in f^{-1}(K)\leftrightarrow f(x)\in K$. And that for $A\subset B$ means that $x\in A \rightarrow x\in B$.

But knowing this how can I proof this? Because I can say $x\in f^{-1}(A)\rightarrow x\in f^{-1}(B)$ So therefore $f(x)\in A \rightarrow f(x)\in B$ But now I don't know if I automatically can say that $A\subset B$ (I don't think so).

Secondly I want to show using a counterexample that $ f^{-1}(A)\subset f^{-1}(B) \rightarrow A\subset B $ Doesn't work.

If someone knows the answer please share your wisdom :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **given** $A\subseteq B$ and **need to show** $f^{-1}(A)\subseteq f^{-1}(B)$. You can show it by proving that every $x\in f^{-1}(A)$ also belongs to $f^{-1}(B)$.

Let $x\in f^{-1}(A)$. Then $f(x)\in A$, so $f(x)\in B$ since $A\subseteq B$. Thus $x\in f^{-1}(B)$.

---

For a counterexample of $f^{-1}(A)\subseteq f^{-1}(B)\implies A\subseteq B$, consider $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with $f(x)=x^2,x\in\Bbb R$. Let $A=[-1,1],B=[0,4]$. Then $f^{-1}(A)=[-1,1],f^{-1}(B)=[-2,2]$ but $A\not\subseteq B$.

Comment: Your counter example needs an edit. they should not be equal but proper subsets

Comment: @AvenDesta Many texts use $\subset$ in place of $\subseteq$. Nevertheless I have fixed my example assuming proper subsets. Also note that the original statement that needs to be proven does not work if you take $\subset$ to mean proper subsets. You may have $A\subset B$ but $f^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(B)$.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, it really helped :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\inv}[1]{f^{-1}[#1]}$
This is my answer.

The inverse image of the mapping $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is defined as, for any $B \subseteq Y$,

$$
f^{-1}[B] = \{x \in X~|~\exists y \in B: f(x) = y\}
$$
Therefore, for all $x\in X$, $x \in f^{-1}[B]$ is equivalent to $f(x) \in B$. We can solve your problem using this property.

Let $A \subseteq B \subseteq Y$. Then, for all $x \in X$, $x \in f^{-1}[A]$ implies $f(x) \in A \subseteq B$, which gives $x\in f^{-1}[B]$. Therefore, $f^{-1}[A] \subseteq f^{-1}[B]$.

Conversely, suppose $f^{-1}[A] \subseteq f^{-1}[B]$. In this case, we don't have much to say. However, if we assume $f$ to be subjective we can conclude $A \subseteq B$. Let $f$ be surjective. Then, for all $y \in A$, there exists $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$, hence $x \in \inv{A} \subseteq \inv{B}$, which gives $y = f(x) \in B$.